# Switching indexOf to inArray

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a nice solution to turn this indexOf into a jQuery [inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/). I'm testing on IE8 and indexOf completely fails. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function parse(datestring) {
    var date = parseInt(datestring.slice(0,2), 10),
        month = shortMonths.indexOf(datestring.slice(2,5).toLowerCase()),
        year = parseInt(datestring.slice(5,9), 10);
    return new Date(year, month, date);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
month = $.inArray(datestring.slice(2,5).toLowerCase(), shortMonths)
```

Personally, I'd leave your code as it is. This has no benefit over what you have now.

Comment: Worked perfectly, I have to change it because it seems IE8< doesn't support IndexOf

Comment: In which case, I feel sorry for you still having to support IE8 and lower :(

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
month = $.inArray(datestring.slice(2, 5).toLowerCase(), shortMonths)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead avoid rewriting code, and add this in front of your code.
It adds indexOf support for those browsers which havent got it.

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
  Array.prototype.indexOf = function (searchElement , fromIndex) {
    var i,
        pivot = (fromIndex) ? fromIndex : 0,
        length;

    if (!this) {
      throw new TypeError();
    }

    length = this.length;

    if (length === 0 || pivot >= length) {
      return -1;
    }

    if (pivot < 0) {
      pivot = length - Math.abs(pivot);
    }

    for (i = pivot; i < length; i++) {
      if (this[i] === searchElement) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    return -1;
  };
}
```

Comment: I've got a solution, just waiting to tick. Nice workaround though, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice polyfill for indexOf available on the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility).